# Cannot format SD card in Windows 7 because I can’t find an option to format in FAT 32?

Tags: windows-7

I want to format my 4GB SD card, but it seems that the "format option" has no "fat 32".

How can I format it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a disk/SD card as FAT32 in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1179871/how-to-format-a-disk-sd-card-as-fat32-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 8):

To format using FAT32, you have to select a partition no larger than 32 GiB (32,768 MiB).

If you try to format a partition larger than 32 GiB (32768 MiB), Disk Management offers exFAT instead of FAT32, because FAT32 is technically incapable of addressing partitions larger than 32 GiB.

I have some Disk Manager screen shots to illustrate this, but this site won't let me post images until I gain 10 "reputaion," whatever that is. So I'll summarize with words:

- If your partition is **32,768 MiB or smaller**, Disk Manager offers the
  **FAT32** file system, and does not provide an option for exFAT.
- If your partition is **32,769 MiB or larger**, Disk Manager offers the
  **exFAT** file system, and does not provide an option for FAT32.

---

***Note**: Disk Manager still uses the old decimal unit MB instead of the correct binary unit MiB. Don't believe it. The maximum size for FAT32 is [32 GiB (32,768 MiB)](https://google.com/#q=32+GiB+in+MiB), not [32 GB (32,000 MB)](https://google.com/#q=32GB+in+MB).*

Comment: FAT32 can work with partitions as large as 2TB (16TB with a slightly non-standard format).  The 32GB limit is a deliberate software decision by Microsoft.

Comment: Of course FAT32 **can** address more than 32 GB. My 128 GB SanDisk Ultra Fit flash drive is factory preformatted to FAT32 (32768 bytes in each allocation unit).

Comment: This answer is accurate. I was able to FAT32 reformat a 64 GB Kingston DTXM UFD using DiskPart on Windows 10 (22H2), with a 64 MB allocation unit, but only when I limited the primary partition size to 32 GiB (32768 MiB). The `filesystems` command showed FAT32, exFAT and NTFS as supported, with FAT32 set as default. When I tried to let the primary partition take up all the space (without specifying size), and FAT32 format it, I got the error `Virtual Disk Service error: The volume size is too big.` Also, FAT32 was not listed and exFAT was set as default in the output of `filesystems`.

Comment: My Kingston DTXM flash drive was brand new, removed from its packaging on the same day that I reformatted it. It came preformatted as FAT32 with a 64 MB allocation unit. I had Ext4 formatted it for use in a Linux system, and then I wanted to reformat it back to FAT32 using DiskPart in Windows and it didn't work. Now I know why. Since it came preformatted with FAT32, I guess they are using Linux in the production. Imagine if Kingston used Windows to produce 64 GB flash drives with only 32 GB of capacity! And then users used Windows to try to make use of the rest of the space! Comical!

Comment: The FAT32 file system can support volumes up to 16 TB, although it's not recommended to stretch it beyond 2 TB. That's still way above the 32 GB limit in Windows. You can find a full explainer about this on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#Maximal_sizes), along with a reference to an article on The Register where Microsoft's Dave Plummer says this (arbitrary) limit exists because he decided so more than two decades ago. He used a 16 MB memory card for reference, multiplied that by 1000 and then doubled it, hence the 32000 MB limit (MiB was not a thing back then).

Answer (score 2):

You can format your SD card by command prompt.

1. Click Start button.
2. Write Cmd in search box.
3. Click on Cmd.
4. Type this command:

   - `C:\user> format H: /FS:FAT32` (where h is your drive letter).
   - Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
   - If it asks for yes/no press Y.
   - Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now your SD card change in Fat32 file system.

Comment: Do you need to be an administrator to do this or will a normal user do?

Comment: I have tried this process many times and no problem

Comment: Normal user can do no need to administrator permission
I have tried this process as a normal user and it will done successfully

Comment: If you don't want to wait heck of a long time, add the /Q for quick format :)

Comment: Update: format failed. My sdcard is >32GB. 

Solution:
Used diskpart to clean up the volume (list disk, select disk <index>, clean, create partition primary). 

Used h2format to format it in FAT32: http://www.heise.de/download/h2format.html

h2format X: 64 (for 64gb)

Answer (score 1):

> it seems that the "format option" has no "fat 32"

That's correct. *Format options* doesn't have an option for FAT32. It doesn't have options for NTFS or other file systems, either.

Use *File system* to set the file system.

[image: FAT32]

Comment: You wont see the FAT32 option if the drive has >32GB space, thats the problem

Comment: Sorry, but it's been a while since I've seen a guy like this...

Comment: I thought I was the pedantic type... but this... this is a different level of pedantry. Although I doubt it, there is still a possibility that the guy who posted the original question was in fact looking for FAT32 in the wrong place (Format options vs. File system). So even though this answer is pedantry by example, this is still a relevant answer. Did you read the original question? Before everyone compounded it with their own formatting problems? How do you explain the absence of FAT32 for a **4 GB** storage device? If you remember from math, 4 is **less than** 32. Now I'm being a pedant.

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively Use Disk Management tool

1. Click run type `Compmgmt.msc`.
2. Under `Storage` choose `Disk management`.
3. Right Click the partition and choose `fat32`.
4. Under filesystem you could find fat32.
5. Click on format and apply.

Comment: Here w10 showed me the option to chose FAT32 while it didn't in File Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

After messing around like others for hours, Searching other forums I found two methods that appear to work. One involved downloading a 'free' program called "fat32format".

**DISCLAIMER: I HAVE NOT DOWNLOADED OR TRIED THIS!**

I'm always a bit uncomfortable downloading programs, but the reports seemed positive. A good security/antivirus program is obviously recommended here.

**THE METHOD I USED**: Because it was easy and simple for me and fortunately available was to just insert the stick into my sons Xbox 360 and it formatted the 128Gb stick to FAT32 in seconds.

I found the posts on a "How to Geek" forum, but felt that I should share it.

Comment: +1 the XBOX 360 method works for me too. Thanks. I want to just add some info, you have to go under System Preferences/Storage Devices and click format on your unformatted usb.

Answer (score 0):

I also had trouble trying to get Windows 10 to format my external 1TB USB drive in FAT32. (I wanted to copy some TV recordings on to it from my Humax HDR Fox T2 hard disc recorder which only reads FAT32 file sytems.)
I found that the Humax would format the drive for me. It took only a few minutes.